# O(n^2) takes 1 second to process 1000 elements. How much time does it take for 8K?

Tags: math, time-complexity, big-o

On a picture parabola n^2 x=1000 will correspond y=1. Still there has to be some coefficient? Is it a*N^2 or (aN)^2?
How to solve correctly in pure math?

Comment: Big-O notation doesn't give you exact results like that - it's only concerned with asymptotic rate of growth.  So you could estimate 64 seconds, but the notation simply does not capture the less-dominant terms of the actual time that would be taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a quadratic function f, that describes a parabola that has the vertex in (0, 0) the function can always be written in the form f: y = a * x^2, where a is any real number except zero, if you want a non-degenerate parabola. Solving for the a coefficient should be quite simple from here - (1000, 1) ∈ f => 1 = a * 1000^2 => a = 1e-6. Therefore the equation for the function f: y = 1e-6 * x^2. This means f(8000) = 64.

The way simpler approach (without computing the function), is the use the rule, that when dealing with quadratic functions, an x-times change in the independant variable will cause a x^2-times change in the dependant varible. Change in the independant variable is 8x => change in the dependant will be 64x => time being 64 seconds.